# Need help in understanding how to solve combinatorial problem involving difference between values

Tags: combinatorics

So here is the problem from the book:

1. Y represents the difference between the number of heads and tails from a coin that was tossed k times. We want to know all possible values of Y.
2. Then, say k = 4. If coin is fair, what are probabilities for the values Y can take?

The solution is given as follows:
Let i denotes the # of heads and j denotes the # of tails when a coin is tossed n times.

Since i+j = n, so j = n-i or i= n-j

Thus Y = i-j = 2i-n, i = 0,...,n

OR alternatively Y = n-2j, j = 0,...,n

As for part two of the problem I think the solution is following:

Y = 4 can occur when TTTT or HHHH   -->
thus: 1/16 + 1/16 = 1/8

Y = 2 can occur when TTTH or HTTT or THTT or TTHT  -->
thus: 4 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 4/16 = 1/4

Y = 0 can occur when TTHH or HHTT or THTH or HTHT  -->
thus: 4 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 * 1/2 = 4/16 = 1/4

But when summing up 1/4 + 1/4 + 1/8 = 5/8 does not equal to 1....not sure where is the mistake here. Did I approach this problem in a right way? Anyone can help? Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $Y=i-j$ and $j=n-i$, so substitute the value of $j$ given by the second into the first to get $Y=i-(n-i)=2i-n$

For the second part, $Y$ is supposed to be signed, so $Y=4$ can only happen with $HHHH$.  Your list for $Y=2$ are really cases where $Y=-2$, and there are four corresponding cases where $Y=2$.  You missed two cases for $Y=0, THHT$ and $HTTH$.  That will make the probabilities sum to $1$.